# How to retrieve text by xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

**Hey everyone**

I am 15 years old and I'm currently making a python/selenium script that automatically loges in on my school page and goes in to see what homework i have tomorrow.

### The way I want it to check if we have received homework is if the text box which is: "LB MAT 86" is something else (because that means we have received homework)

Let me now tell you about my problem:

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLjuR.png

But first, let me tell u how my "homework page" is designed and works.

On the picture you see that I have inspected the text: "LB MAT 86".

- LB is the abbreviation of my teachers name.
- MAT stands for "matematik" with just means math in english.
- 86 is the class number our class have.

When we get homework our teacher deletes the text "LB MAT 86" and instead writes the homework we get.

My question for you is how can I find the text. The only way I can see how you can find the text is by its location.

The xpath of the text field: //*[@id="sk-diary-notes-container"]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/text()[1]

The full xpath of the text field: /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/text()[1]

OuterHTML:   LB MAT 86

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[contains(@align,'center')//td[contains(.,'LB MAT 86')]")
```

Would get the element with text LB MAT 86.

You can add some code to find the current index to check for your code. /tr[i]/td[i]

Comment: Hey Arundeep. Yes, but the problem is that my teacher deletes the text "LB MAT 86" and instead writes our homework in the textfield. You understand what I mean?

Comment: He wants you to learn how to use split. It's mine assumption. Learn it

Comment: Yeah he wants split after you find the element by the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `xpath`

```
locator = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[contains(@align,'center')/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]")
```

You should get everything including nbsp (non-braking space).
Then split the result and get everything after `nbsp;`

You did not include html code, only screenshot. Next time include it (or include it now).
After you test the correct locator, try to use split(). It will get the last element from your text divided by space. I am not 100%  sure it will work, experiment by yourself.

```
mystring = locator.text
desired_text = result = mystring.split(' ')[-1]
```

Comment: I have changed it now. I just copied the outerHTML. Hope that was what you were talking about. I have only been using python for 1 week

Comment: Try the locator. Also, do you have the link to your site?

Comment: Hey Vitaliis. I can unfortunately not give u the site because u need a student login to access it.

Comment: I hope my advice will help you.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote&accept if the answer is helpful )

Comment: Hey Vitaliis. I keep keeting errors when i use your code. Picture: file:///Users/andreassorensen/Desktop/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202021-04-08%20kl.%2008.08.50.png